# Translation of a theorem in French

Tags: partial-differential-equations, soft-question, translation-request, mathematical-french

As picture below, what is uno fonction ?  I use google translate , it fail to translate it .

> [image]

Comment: it is written une fonction which mean a function do you want a full translation of the theorem ?

Comment: Old typewriter, producing `e`s that look like `o`s.

Comment: This does not look like a complete statement. I see the condition on the function $\varphi$, but no statement about what properties $\varphi$ might have.

Comment: @Lubin  Yes, I have add a complete. In fact , I don't know it is not complete befor you tell me :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Translation:

> Lemma 4.1. Let $\varphi(t)$ be a function defined for $t \ge k_0$ non-negative and non-decreasing such that if $h > k \ge k_0$ we have: $$\varphi(h) \le \frac{c}{(h-k)^\alpha} [\varphi(k)]^\beta$$
>   $c,\alpha,\beta$ being positive constants.
>
> Then, (i) if $\beta > 0$ we have ...
>   where

[similarly for cases (ii) and (iii)]

Comment: In French, the words "positif" and "négatif" mean "nonnegative" and "non-positive", respectively, don't they? Does that affect the translation?

Comment: @TannerSwett, given the occurrence of both "non négative" and "positives" in the original sentence, I think the translation is faithful.

Comment: @6005, thanks for adding the formulas.